# Looping and web scraping. How to scrape multiple elements

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape betting odds off a site. Currently my code can print the last odd of the game off but not them all. Any ideas of what i am doing wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
my_url = 'https://www.sportsbet.com.au/betting/australian-rules'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")

price_texts = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"priceText_f71sibe"})
filename = "odds.csv"
f = open(filename,"w")
headers = "odds team 1\n"

f.write(headers)



for price_text in price_texts:
    odds = price_text.span.text

print("odds are: "+odds)

f.write(odds)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it only print the last odds, since you write the `print` and `f.write()` section outside the `for` loop. The `odds` value will change every time until the loop stop. You should make them inside the loop by adding indentation on the `print` and `f.write(odds)`:

```
for price_text in price_texts:
    odds = price_text.span.text
    print("odds are: "+ odds)
    f.write(odds)
```

Comment: Bloody hell it was that simple. Thank you